# Calling Web Service: Identity check failed for outgoing message

Tags: c#, web-services, ssis

We are having a problem when accessing web service using our SSIS package.
Our package is already working before but suddenly we got error when accessing the web service.
Today they fix the issue in the SSL, however, we got new error when connecting to http://abc.sample.com:81/WebService or http://abc.sample.com:81/WebService?wsdl.

> SSWS_CallWebService (1):
> Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was 'abc.sample.com' but the remote endpoint provided DNS claim 'www.abc.sample.com'. If this is a legitimate remote endpoint, you can fix the problem by explicitly specifying DNS identity 'www.abc.sample.com' as the Identity property of EndpointAddress when creating channel proxy.

Browsing to https://abc.sample.com and checking the certificate, the certificate is issued to abc.sample.com and it has 2 Subject Alternative Name (SAN).

[SSL Cert of abc.sample.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCDUV.png)

[2 SAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScsGw.png)

Below is what I have tried but still no luck.

- Change the URL from http://abc.sample.com:81/WebService to  http://www.abc.sample.com:81/WebService but still no luck.

Can you please help me figure out what's wrong and what should I do to resolve it?

Appreciate your help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. There should only be 1 SAN such as [www.abc.sample.com](http://www.abc.sample.com). Thank you.